# laravel 5 get ID from relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a Project Model and in it I have

```
protected $table = 'projects';
protected $guarded = [];

public function docOne()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\DocOne', 'id');
}
```

In the Model DocOne, I have

```
protected $table = 'doc_one';
protected $guarded = [];

public function project()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Project', 'id');
}
```

So it is a one to one relationship.  Now I have a form which collects information to fill in the doc_one table.  In the controller, I do

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $input = Input::all();
    DocOne::create( $input );

    return Redirect::route('projects.index')->with('message', 'Document saved');
}
```

This fails because the database also expects the project ID.  How can I get the id for the project that is creating doc_one?

Thanks

Comment: Does your table has a filed project_id? when do you create projects?  before or after you create docone? or at the same time as you create docone?

Comment: Projects are created before docone.

Comment: In that case, you want to get the last inserted/created project id and pass it to your doc one create query.

Comment: What's your form look like?

Answer (score 1):

To create doc associated with the project, your route should be like this:

```
Route::post('projects/{id}/doc_one', 'DocOneController@store');
```

Then your controller's method will be:

```
public function store(Request $request, $id)
{
    /**
     * Create DocOne
     */
}
```

Where `$id` is your project ID.